# Faulty GPO Deployment Over Wifi

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, deployment, windows-10, print-server

We are experiencing a strange behaviour in our environment. I'd be glad if anybody might have some fresh ideas to help me with.

*Scenario:*
We created a new Print and Documents Service on a Windows Server 2012, which is responsible for sharing our printers and providing mandatory drivers. We are using a Group Policy to deploy those printers to Windows 10 machines. Everything works fine over Ethernet **but** using Wifi no printers are installed. Even though GPOs are applied and listed in gpresult no printer is installed.

What could cause this phenomenon?

It's my first question on Server Fault. Please tell me if you need further informations.

Thanks!

Comment: Check to see if your WiFi network is within the same subnet as the wired connections - if it is not, you'll need to verify that the ports used to connect shared printers are not blocked from one network to the other. 

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1322110  has a list of all the ports associated with shared printers in both Linux/Unix and Windows environments.

Comment: ^ Agreed. Can you access the print server and printers directly from the wireless network?

Comment: Thank you all for a quick response. Everything is accessible over wifi. Pages can be printed, print Server can be reached. Wired and wireless connection is within the same subnet as well. Can it be that Windows 10 does not bother downloading drivers over wifi?

Comment: What happen if you double click the printer, from explorer, that does not want to install by GPO ?

Comment: No printer is deployed via GPO using WiFi. Therefore, I can not double click the printer in explorer because it is not yet installed. I probably do not understand what you mean.